# Suggest a (nonparametric?) test for the difference between two strictly-positive distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, nonparametric, bootstrap, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

$\mathbf{X}$ is a $n\times p$ matrix of data.  I'm treating $\mathbf{X}$ as having a multivariate normal distribution with some arbitrary covariance structure.

$\mathbf{Y}$ is a $(m<n)\times p$ matrix of the same variables.  $\mathbf{Y}$ is also multivariate normal (or is being approximated as such anyway...).

I'm mostly interested in whether $\mathbf{Y}$ has the same variance (in a multivariate sense) as $\mathbf{X}$.  So, irrespective of whether the correlation structure has changed, is a random draw from $\mathbf{Y}$ likely to be further from the origin than a random draw of $\mathbf{X}$?

Here is how I am thinking of doing this so far:

$\mathbf{d_X}$ is a n-vector of Mahalanobis distances from the mean of $\mathbf{X}$, which has been centered and column-wise de-trended, and scaled by its covariance matrix

$\mathbf{d_Y}$ is a n-vector of "Mahalanobis distances" from the mean of $\mathbf{Y}$, which has been centered and column-wise de-trended, and scaled by $\mathbf{X}$'s covariance matrix, rather than by its own

I'm thinking that my question above will be answered if I can make a statement about the likelihood that $\mathbf{d_Y}$ is a series of draws from $\mathbf{d_X}$, or whether the $\mathbf{d_Y}$ are drawn from a different distribution.

$n$ is time in my application, and $\mathbf{d_X}$ comes before $\mathbf{d_Y}$.  I'd calculate some statistic to answer my question, and then apply a block bootstrap to get the distribution of the statistic.

But what is a good choice?  I know that Mahalanobis distances follow a $\chi^2$ distribution.  I suppose that $\mathbf{d_X}$ will follow a $\chi^2$ with p degrees of freedom.  Each element of $\mathbf{d_Y}$ can be assessed with a  p-value for the likelihood that it is a draw from the $\chi^2$.  But what about the whole of the $\mathbf{d_Y}$?

Perhaps the thing to do would be to get a a distribution of bootstrapped Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistics?  But I'd appreciate recommendations, not having done a lot of non-parametric testing of equality of distributions before.

Comment: This will be impossible to answer until you provide some kind of probability model.

Comment: I don't entirely follow.  Probability model for what?  Do you mean the distribution from which $\mathbf{X}$ is drawn?  I'm assuming/approximating it as multivariate normal...  As such, $\mathbf{d_X}$ should follow a $\chi^2$ distribution.  Given that I am using a covariance matrix calculated from data, and given that I am centering the mean to $\mathbf{0}$, I suppose it follows $\chi^2$ by construction...

Comment: In your post, you only assert that $X$ is a matrix: that implies nothing about any probability distributions.  Please be explicit about such assumptions in your question. It is stated so abstractly that the least little omission will render it unanswerable or turn it into a question you did not intend to ask. You would do better to provide some context so your readers will be able to understand your situation even if you haven't perfectly described it.

Comment: I guess the fact that I am taking Mahalanobis distance implies that I'm treating it as multivariate normal, but I'll make that more explicit.

Comment: Edited for more detail...